# singular or plural in "noun in apposition" structure

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Frescos depicting episodes from the Khmer version of the Ramayana, the Reamker is/are painted on the wall.

In this sentence, which verbs I should use, singular or plural?

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence is **frescos**, so the correct verb form is plural, **are**.  The sentence is made a little less clear by all the intervening information, but it effectively says

> Frescos...are painted on the wall.

"depicting episodes from the Khmer version of the Ramayana, the Reamker" is a descriptive phrase modifying **frescos**.